I need a way to automate an existing script which contains DIALOG
I have an existing BASH script which needs user input.
To automate other things, I already have a bash script that contains lots of other code.
So the solution should be implementable in bash.
I have already automated parts of the original script which also contain DIALOG boxes.
This is solved with EXPECT so far.
These DIALOGs however don't contain any selection, only marking and confirming.
I have now gotten stuck because I need to select an option in the DIALOG box with SPACEBAR.
I can't continue the original script without the option selected.
So my guess is to either send the space to the DIALOG box or find another key that works to select the option other than SPACEBAR.
This is the relevant part of the code I have:
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect << 'HEREDOC'
spawn /opt/eri_sn/sbin/foo.bar
sleep 1
send -- {r r}
send -- \r
expect eof
HEREDOC

With this current code the Option is not selected, only confirmed with the RETURN and thus the original script fails.
Manually, the option does get selected by pressing SPACEBAR.
I also tried sending the SPACEBAR via Hex Code (send -- r\x20r\r).
Trying to only send the SPACEBAR resulted in nothing sent in a test script, so send -- {r r} is a solution for this.
Also, I tried to get the needed lines via autoexpect. This however also only shows:
send -- " "
send -- "\r"

Also, there isn't a way to call the original script in a way that would make this work.
I know I could copy all relevant parts out of the original script, but it's from the manufacturer and might change with different versions.
Thanks in advance

please use a [repro].

The utility expect is called expect because typically you need to use the command expect within the script to match what the spawned command is writing back. Only when you match the appropriate output should the script then use send to reply. Your example is probably using send too early, before the dialog has finished preparing itself for the reply.

Your problem is likely in 2-3 lines of code. A simpler version of the min. repo. ex. is in the bash wiki.  Search for "How to turn a bad script into a good question". Good luck.

I was creating a minimal reproducible example, like pynexj said, when I realized that I just had another line of send -- \r in my code.
Because of this, everything I tried didn't matter, and I was just wasting my time.
The question might as well be deleted, sorry.

In one of my projects (https://www.hackster.io/abouhatab/raspberry-pi-on-any-wi-fi-even-with-captive-portal-rev-2-0804db#code) I used xdotool to resolve a similar issue. I used tab to get to the option before pressing space.

Thanks for your answer, but getting to the option isn't the problem.
However, I have seen people write about xdotool, trouble is I can't just install it on every system I encounter.
